# Can I constrain 1 axis in bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I'm using bokeh to display events over a long period of time.  The events are binary, so there's no requirement to be able to scale the y-axis, and in fact it looks quite odd when panning and zooming that the height of the events changes.

This is particularly a problem with zooming, since it zooms in both axes.

Is there a way I can constrain the axes, so there's no way to pan and zoom in y, while still being able to pan and zoom in x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the pan and zoom tools have dimensions which can be independently specified:

```
plot = bk.figure(tools="reset,hover,wheel_zoom,pan")
pan_tool = plot.select(dict(type=PanTool))
pan_tool.dimensions=["width"]
zoom_tool = plot.select(dict(type=WheelZoomTool))
zoom_tool.dimensions=["width"]
```